# Selendroid webdriver initialisation error occuring

Tags: android, selendroid

I am making an android application which will login to my college website then clicks on attendance button on the page , scraps data ,perform some calculations and shows to the user but I can't find any way from here. I am using selendroid for this. The problem is with the driver variable. In java application I can use ChromeDriver but for android what to use?

```
package com.example.jtx.gneattendance;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import java.util.List;
import io.selendroid.SelendroidCapabilities;
import io.selendroid.SelendroidDriver;
import io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int count = 0;
String arr[] = new String[15];
String atten = "";
TextView text;



public void cnt() throws Exception


{
    WebDriver driver =null;
    driver.get("https://academics.gndec.ac.in");

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/button")).click();
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr"));

    String p[] = new String[rows.size() + 1];
    int pheld[] = new int[rows.size() + 1];
    int pattende[] = new int[rows.size() + 1];
    Double ppercent[] = new Double[rows.size() + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows.size(); i++) {
        p[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]")).getText();
        pheld[i] = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[4]")).getText());
        pattende[i] = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[5]")).getText());
        ppercent[i] = Double.valueOf((driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[6]")).getText()));

        if (ppercent[i] < 75.0) {
            lecreq(pattende[i], pheld[i]);
        }

        arr[i] = " Subject name=" + p[i] + "<br> Lectures held=" + pheld[i] + " <br>  Lectures Attended=" + pattende[i] + " <br>  Percentage=" + ppercent[i] + " <br>  Lectures needed=" + count + "<br><br><br>";
        // System.out.println(arr[i]);
        text = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(arr[i]);

    }



}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        cnt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void lecreq(int m, int n) {
    if ((m * 100 / n) < 75.0) {
        m++;
        n++;
        count++;
        lecreq(m, n);
    }
}






}
```